# Find non-ascii spaces in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a large database where things like Trim and functions I made to count words don't always work (some records still have 'spaces' and multi-word fields get a count of 1). Leading me to believe I have non-ascii spaces.

I tried this to find offending records:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD NOT REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9 ;,]'
```

in other words all letters, digits, characters I used and space.

Returns zero-set.

Is there a better way to do this (i.e. one that works)?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will match rows that have one or more characters in the set {`A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, space, semicolon, colon}.

Better to look specifically for non-printable characters using the POSIX `[:cntrl:]` character class:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD REGEXP '[[:cntrl:]]'
```